# How to set the screen resolution in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, screen-resolution

I am making a settings menu for my game. I have created every graphics setting I want, except changing the screen resolution. This is what I tried first. I didn't know what I should provide for the target, though.


[What I tried first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWZ18.png)


For some reason, this didn't work. I'm guessing I should have provided a different target. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a PC game? If so, this is the node I've used for altering resolution in the past, utilizing the r.setRes command:

[image]

If you have variable [width] x [height] parameters, have a function build the string and pass the return value to that node. Note: after the WxH, the f stands for fullscreen.

Credit for image: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/26895/how-can-i-change-games-resolution-in-blueprints.html

Comment: Will the resolution appear different in the editor, or will I have to build my project to see the resolution change?

Comment: If you're launching in the editor I believe you'll have to launch the preview in a separate window and it should show the res change. Don't use the standard integrated preview.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is one of the highest results on google I figured I'd reply here.

Using console commands to set resolution absolutely DOES NOT WORK for shipping builds where console commands are disabled. It's better to use Get Game User Settings + Set Screen Resolution + Apply Resolution Settings nodes.

Comment: This solution, as well as the command one, did not work for me when trying to set the resolution of my game to 320x180. The only way I found to do this is by rendering to a target and using the produced texture as an input in a post-process material.